# Error handling with Observables in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass any errors that might occur in an HTTP request to a common logging service from all my services:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

constructor(logger: LoggerService) { }

doSomething(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
        .post('/foo/bar', {})
        .catch(this.notifyErrors);
}

protected notifyErrors(error: any): Observable<any> {
    this.logger.log(error);

    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Unfortunately, inside the `notifyErrors` method, `this` is lost. I've tried defining this as a fat arrow, but i get type errors from the TS compiler. I've used the exact syntax in the Observable documentation.

Comment: Gunter, has a more elegant solution. I like his better than mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pass function references, you need to fix `this`

```ts
 .catch(this.notifyErrors.bind(this));
```

or alternatively

```ts
 .catch(() => this.notifyErrors());
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score -1):

I have not run your code, but if you want to access this, you may have to pass it in.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

constructor(logger: LoggerService) { }

doSomething(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
        .post('/foo/bar', {})
        .catch(err => {
            this.notifyErrors(err, this);
        });
}

protected notifyErrors(error, that): Observable<any> {
    that.logger.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Comment: `err => { this.notifyErrors(err, this); }` does not work. The compiler gives me: Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Response>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: Or Use Gunters answer.